# xstream, how to serialize a list to xml

Tags: java, collections, xstream

I am using xstream and trying to serialize a List to XML.  I need an output structure like

```
<Employees>
  <Employee></Employee>
  <Employee></Employee>
  <Employee></Employee>
</Employees>
```

The object to serialize would be something like an

```
 List<Employee>
```

or a class Employees.  I've tried to create an Employees as

```
public class Employees extends ArrayList<Employee>(){}
```

and various other approaches but can't get it to serialize as I need it.  Is there an easy way to do such a thing?

My question is similar to [XStream - Root as a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136234/xstream-root-as-a-collection-of-objects) but I'd like to do it without a wrapper object.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a list as your root element? You can alias the class. The code below produces the output you're looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees.add(new Employee());
    employees.add(new Employee());
    employees.add(new Employee());
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("Employees", List.class);
    System.out.println(xstream.toXML(employees));
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to use it correctly but what would the field name be if Users extends ArrayList?  xstream.addImplicitCollection(Users.class, "??")

Comment: xstream.alias("Employees", Users.class);
I believe you'd need a custom converter at that point. http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html